# How to summarize multiple exon copy numbers into copy number of the corresponding gene

Tags: gene, cnv, exon

I have a matrix, sample by exon, containing a copy number value for each pair (sample, exon). I would like to generate a second matrix, sample by gene, where the copy number of the exons is consolidated in a single value per gene.

Due to the nature of copy number alteration, I am not sure if this is meaningful, or feasible (e.g., how can it be summarized, in the case a gene is interested by 2 alterations with different copy numbers?).

Is there a common approach that is used in this case?

##### Edit

A possible example is the following:

```
         gene1_exon1  gene1_exon2  gene1_exon3 ... geneN_exonM
sample1            2            1            1               0
sample2            2            2            1               0
...
sampleJ            3            2            2               2
```

A possible summarized matrix (with majority voting - not sure if this would be the best approach):

```
         gene1 ... geneN
sample1      1         0
sample2      2         0
...
sampleJ      2         2
```

I believe this is more an issue related to the biological interpretation than the actual implementation (i.e., I am already implementing a function in `pandas`). My concern is on the interpretation, since my prototype select as gene copy number the majority copy number from its exons. However, this has some caveats (e.g., what if you have a GAIN on an exon, and a LOSS on a second exon, for the same gene - will you call GAIN or LOSS?). The big picture is that I want to compare two samples CNAs at the gene level, but I could not find this task discussed online.

The main objective of this summarization is to compute gene level concordance between samples. Exon-level or base-level concordance is computed in parallel, in order to have different CNA granularities.

However, one might not use the majority voting proposed and, e.g., call a CNA on a gene if the alteration is found in at least p% of exons (e.g., 30% of exons) - this is just an example, I am not suggesting to use this approach.

Comment: You might be interested in the approach we took when trying to find CNVs that overlap known, reported ones. have a look at our documentation here: https://varsome.com/about/resources/sv-implementation/. I'll try and get the relevant bits into an answer if I get the chance.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it

Comment: Take it with a pinch of salt, of course: that was not peer reviewed and was just the best system we could come up with based on our own best judgment. That said, I do think it is a reasonable approach, I am just aware that I have been wrong before! :)